# How to load user and its custom fields like picture, title in drupal8?

Tags: drupal-8

I want to display user picture and user title in node detail page , say for content type "blog"

Please suggest how this can be achieved...

Answer (score 0):

You can load user object and get the fields values like below example.

```
$user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($user_id);

//Getting the values

$user_name = $user->get('field_disaply_name')->value;
```

Comment: How to display username based on user who created a node in twig file?